# What do I do with the giant spinning pot?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

In Ocarina of Time, in Goron City, there is a giant pot with an angry looking face that is sitting on the bottom floor of the city. If you light up all of the torches in the area the pot is in, it begins to spin. Is there anything I can do to the pot? I tried throwing bombs in from above, but kept missing. Should I keep trying?

Comment: I once managed to jump in the damn pot thinking there was a hidden level in there, all it did was send me back to spawn 

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you should keep trying!  I had a tough time getting a bomb in the first time I played as well.  Spoilers from strategywiki.org:

> After opening Darunia's house, light the four torches around the pot at the bottom of Goron City. From the second level, **throw a Bomb Flower into the top of the spinning pot to stop it.** It will stop showing one of three faces, depending on what time you threw the bomb flower in. Alternatively you can wait until after you get bombs from dodongo's cavern and use them instead. **If the pot stops on 'happy', a Heart Piece will fly out.**
>  
>  http://strategywiki.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Ocarina_of_Time/Heart_Containers

Comment: The first four words of the second sentence of that spoiler are the most important. You should *not* attempt this from any other higher spot.